# How to make custom changes in shopify checkout page using edit code?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template, shopify-activemerchant

How to make custom changes in shopify checkout page (like removing existing fields and adding another element) using edit code.
I want to change form style and field, but stuck in the code flow.

```
       <div class="content" data-content>
          <div class="wrap">        
            <div class="main" role="main">
              <div class="main__header">
                {{ content_for_logo }}  // It comes from where ?
                {{ breadcrumb }} // It comes from where ?
                {{ alternative_payment_methods }} // It comes from where ?
              </div>          
              <div class="main__content">                 
                {{ content_for_layout }}  // It comes from where ?
              </div>
              <div class="main__footer">            
                {{ content_for_footer }}           
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar" role="complementary">
              <div class="sidebar__header">
                {{ content_for_logo }} // It comes from where ?
              </div>
              <div class="sidebar__content">
                {{ content_for_order_summary }} // It comes from where ?
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: These are the Shopify checkout global objects for checkout page, you can modify the inputs fields into checkout page

Comment: Check more about the [checkout object](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#checkout)

Answer (score 1):

You can't unfortunately, even with Plus. Those fields are generated via a single Liquid tag `{{ content_for_layout }}`.

Any changes to those areas will need to be done using JavaScript.